# Python: a type error

Tags: python-3.4

So here is my situation. Ive been trying to make a advanced calculator in python 3.4, one where you can just type something like this. '1 + 1', and it would then give you the answer of '2'. Now i will explain how my calculator is supposed to work. So you start by entering a maths equation, then it counts the words you entered based on the spaces. It does this so it knows how long some future loops need to be. Then it splits up everything that you entered. It splits it up into str's and int's but its all still in the same variable and it's all still in order. The thing i'm having trouble with is when it is meant to actually do the calculations.

here is all of my code-

```
    # This is the part were they enter the maths equation
    print("-------------------------")
    print("Enter the maths equation")
    user_input = input("Equation: ")
    # This is were it counts all of the words
    data_count = user_input.split(" ")
    count = data_count.__len__()
    # Here is were is splits it into str's and int's
    n1 = 0
    data = []
    if n1 <= count:
        for x in user_input.split():
            try:
                data.append(int(x))
            except ValueError:
                data.append(x)
            n1 += 1
    # And this is were it actually calculates everything
    number1 = 0
    number2 = 0
    n1 = 0
    x = 0
    answer = 0
    while n1 <= count:
        #The code below checks if it is a number
        if data[n1] < 0 or data[n1] > 0:
            if x == 0:
                number1 = data[n1]
            elif x == 1:
                number2 = data[n1]
        elif data[n1] is "+":
            if x == 0:
                answer += number1
            elif x == 1:
                answer += number2
        n1 += 1
        x += 1
        if x > 1:
            x = 0
    print("Answer =", answer)
```

but during the calculation it messes up and gives me and error

error-

```
    if data[n1] < 0 or data[n1] > 0:
    TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

can anyone see what i am doing wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: "#The code below checks if it is a number" Except that it doesn't.

Comment: Really? Ok if it doesn't then would you have any  idea of how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are comparing a string and an integer, this problem comes.
Python doesn't guess, it throws an error.
To fix this, simply call int() to convert your string to an integer:

```
int(input(...))
```

So, corrected statement should be:

```
if int(data[n1]) < 0 or int(data[n1]) > 0:
```

Comment: No, not this. Read the loop above.